# OpenTTD NewGRF WebRequests

Tags: openttd

As part of a university project, I'd like to connect certain events like

- cargo unloaded
- cargo transfered
- money received

with a custom made service / send HTTP Web Requests from within OpenTTD. I'm still rather confused about the languages used to create newgrfs. As far as I understand, for NewGRFs, the language of choice is NML which is a custom built language built ontop of python.

My questions now are

- Is my plan doable?
- Is it possible to use a well-known language to connect to openttd such as C, C++ or Python?

Comment: this might be better off on [so](https://stackoverflow.com), but go check it out first don't 100% trust me on that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want isn't possible without extensive modification to OpenTTD.  [NML](https://newgrf-specs.tt-wiki.net/wiki/NML:Main) is a domain-specific language built on top of [GRF](https://newgrf-specs.tt-wiki.net/wiki/Main_Page), not Python.  It doesn't have any functionality that the underlying GRF language doesn't, and GRF is designed around the needs of a mid-1990s single-player game.

Your best bet is to add your functionality to OpenTTD itself where you can work in C++, rather than trying to modify a language that was never meant to do anything even remotely like what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. In that case, I'm gonna try and fork it. Best wishes :)